# Category page and Article. How?

Tags: categories, templates, url

EDIT!!!

It's not about categories, it's about addresses and templates.

I need to get 2 types of pages:

site.com/sport/football/ — page with lots of entry
site.com/sport/football/realmadrid — page with one entry

Sport - group, Football - template, Realmadrid - it's entry ({url_title})

The blog entry site.com/sport/football/realmadrid is built on the basis of the template Football. And it works well, the right address is obtained. But i need to have site.com/sport/football/ give a completely different template, in which there will be a list of all the records and with a different design. But it is already occupied by entry template.

Answer (score 1):

take a look at Low's [Seg2Cat](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-seg2cat).
It's a free plugin that will allow you to use category names in the url to easily display the category contents on a page instead of messing with cat ids.

Using Seg2Cat will allow you to specify the category to use in your template tags without messing with cat_id in the URL.

For example, you have a template group called products and you want to have a category display page.  Lets use shirts as an example so you would have a template in the products group called shirts.

Your URL would be domain/products/shirts

To display a specific category on the shirts page you could set your channel entries tag to detect the 3rd segment as a category.

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="yourchannel" category="{segment_3_category_id}"}
```

This would allow you to use the 3rd segment to define the id.
The brilliant thing is that you can just use your category_url and seg2cat will work out the correct id to use.
Following the example above, your url could be domain/products/shirts/mens_dress_shirts or domain/products/shirts/ladies_knit_shirts or whatever else.
As long as the segment pattern has a valid category_url, you should be fine and you can then use a single template to display multiple categories.

There are other tags available to display your category name, parent cat, etc.  Check out the plugins documentation for more examples.

Comment: Hello! And which template will refer URL with category?

Comment: I have added further information above that may help.

Comment: I'm a little wrong. It's not about categories.

I need to get 2 pages:

site.com/sport/football/ — page with lots of entry
site.com/sport/football/realmadrid — page with one entry

Sport - group, Football - template, Realmadrid - it's entry ({url_title})

The blog entry realmadrid is built on the basis of the template Football. And it works well, the right address is obtained. But i need to have site.com/sport/football/ give a completely different template, in which there will be a list of all the records and with a different design. But it is already occupied by entry template.

Comment: if I'm understanding you correctly, it sounds like you'll need to place a conditional on the football template so that when segment_3 (realmadrid) is present, you get a single entry view and when the segment is not present you get the category view.

Comment: ok, thx, i will try. ;) And… maybe is it better to use a Pages module?

Comment: 'the football template so that when segment_3 (realmadrid) is present, you get a single entry view and when the segment is not present you get the category view'

It's right. But single view should be with a different design. Is this possible?

Comment: Good method from Slack Chat: {if segment_3 == ""} Football landing page {/if} {if segment_3 != ""} Single entry page {/if}